# action when component state changed

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans, jcheckbox

I have a series of radio buttons generated as an array and displayed in a jPanel.

I want a series of checkboxes in a second panel to be enbled when the radio buttons are in output state but not in the input (input or output are the radio choices).

I want to call the checking state method whenever any of the radiobuttons states change but don't know how to do this as they are created in an array.

Currently the method is called only when the radio button panel is actually clicked.

```
package my.ArduinoGUI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class ArduinoGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public ArduinoGUI() {
    initCustomComponents();
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    digitalPinPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Outputs"));
    jPanel1.setName("Outputs"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 209, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 106, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    digitalPinPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Digital Pin State"));
    digitalPinPanel.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            digitalPinPanelMouseReleased(evt);
        }
    });
    digitalPinLabelArray = new javax.swing.JLabel[digitalPinTotal];
    digitalPinRadioButtonArray = new javax.swing.JRadioButton[digitalPinTotal][2];
    digitalPinGroupArray = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup[digitalPinTotal];
    for(int x = 0; x < digitalPinTotal ; x++) {
        digitalPinGroupArray[x] = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup(); // populate button group
        digitalPinLabelArray[x] = new javax.swing.JLabel(); // populate label array
        digitalPinLabelArray[x].setText("Pin " + (x +2));
        digitalPinPanel.add(digitalPinLabelArray[x]); // add label to panel
        for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++){
            digitalPinRadioButtonArray[x][y] = new javax.swing.JRadioButton(); // populate radio button array
            if (y == 0) {digitalPinRadioButtonArray[x][y].setText("Input");}
            if (y == 1) {digitalPinRadioButtonArray[x][y].setText("Output"); digitalPinRadioButtonArray[x][y].setSelected(true);
            }

            digitalPinGroupArray[x].add(digitalPinRadioButtonArray[x][y]); // assign radio buttons to group
            digitalPinPanel.add(digitalPinRadioButtonArray[x][y]); // add buttons to panel
        }

    }

    jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Generated Boxes"));
    digitalPinOutputArray = new javax.swing.JCheckBox[digitalPinTotal];

    for(int x = 0; x < digitalPinTotal ; x++) {
        digitalPinOutputArray[x] = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        digitalPinOutputArray[x].setText("Output Pin " + (x+2));

        jPanel3.add(digitalPinOutputArray[x]);

    }

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Analog Pin State"));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 126, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(digitalPinPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 159, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 199, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(digitalPinPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    digitalPinPanel.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("DigitalPins");

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void digitalPinPanelMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

// if output selected enable checkbox otherwise disable it
    for (int x = 0; x < digitalPinTotal; x++) {

        if (digitalPinRadioButtonArray[x][0].isSelected() == true) {
            digitalPinOutputArray[x].setEnabled(false);
        }

        if (digitalPinRadioButtonArray[x][1].isSelected() == true) {
            digitalPinOutputArray[x].setEnabled(true);
        }

    }

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ArduinoGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ArduinoGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ArduinoGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ArduinoGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ArduinoGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
private javax.swing.JPanel digitalPinPanel;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
// End of variables declaration
private int digitalPinTotal = 12;
private int analogPinTotal = 8;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox[] digitalPinOutputArray;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton[][] digitalPinRadioButtonArray;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup[] digitalPinGroupArray;
private javax.swing.JLabel[] digitalPinLabelArray;

private void initCustomComponents() {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    // create checkbox array
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 digitalPinRadioButtonArray[x][y].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Output"))
                            {
                                    digitalPinOutputArray[2].setSelected(true);
                            }

                }
            });
```

try this

Comment: Thanks, I also just worked out that adding an action listener to each Radiobutton as it is created works nicely. Thanks for your quick response.